# Phalcon route not working, all urls access index

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I use phalcon-dev-tools-v2.0.13 create a project named `test`,I accessed root url `"/"`,it worked!then,I change some code like this:
[image]

it worked!

[image]

but:

[image]

i add another url ，it didn't work!

[image]

what's the matter? I'm a Phalcon fresher，i followed the Phalcon doc.
My system is `php5.6.30` `Phalcon2.0.13`,  `nginx` conf file is:

```
server {
             listen      80;
             server_name test;
             root /Users/ryugou/test/public;
             index  index.php index.html index.htm;
             charset     utf-8;

      location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
     }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files     $uri =404;

         fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index /index.php;

         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
         fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }

     location ~ /\.ht {
         deny all;
     }
}
```

Comment: How did you configure your Phalcon routes?

Comment: no, i didn't. It's just an example of Phalcon-dev-tools-v2.13 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is on nginx configuration file. You are not passing _url on location block-

modify location block as (careful last part)-

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
    }
```

check [Phalcon Nginx Config](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/nginx.html)